# Moving items in nested list, overflowing to previous/next index of parent list if needed?

Tags: kotlin

I have a `List<Week>` where each `Week` has a `List<Day>`.

My intention is to move a specific day by N indexes; and if that lands it outside of the current week it resides in - move it to the appropiate week.

How would I go about doing this?

---

*Ive tried flatMapping the list of weeks, so that all days are laid out in one giant list and I can simply move the day in that list. This works, but I end up with a new list of days and I have no idea how Id put it back together.*

Comment: Need more info. Is a Week always an exhaustive list of seven specific consecutive dates? Are Days simply dates (I'm thinking no, because they can be moved) or events with a time? Are there sometimes gaps between Weeks because there are no Days in some weeks?

Comment: Thats my bad. There arent any constraints on the lists, e.g. there can be any number of "days" in a given week for this particular scenario.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I understood your problem properly but I'll give it a try anyway.

Basically, you have a matrix `NxM` (where `N=7` and `M=weeks.size`) where each row represents a week.

Suppose you have a day with index `(i0,j0)` which you want to move `k` positions forward (or backward if `k` is negative). So you just need to calculate new target index `(i1,j1)` based on this input.

It's easy to see that `(i1,j1) = (i0 + k/N, j0 + k%N)`

```
fun getNewPosition(src: Point, k: Int): Point {
    return Point(src.x + k/7, src.y + k%7)
}
```

`point.x` is the number of week and `point.y` is the number of day.

Now you need to decide what you should do

1. if you don't have that index in your structure,
2. if you already have a day with that index.

Comment: Youre on the right track! I chose a horrible example by using days above (sorry): so please consider them special weeks where there can be any number of days. I think that complicates things quite a bit?

Comment: Well, there is an obvious solution (iterating over rows and subtracting their sizes from k until k < row.size) but it couldn't be less elegant :(